# How to show n layer nested json object by Angular Js?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I have a menu that uses `ul` and `li`. I want to display it by Angular and JSON object.

I try to do it by `ng-repeat` but my problem is if my object has 20 layer nested object or in the other hand it has n layer nested children how to display it?

code in html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in model">
    {{item.text}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and my json object is :

```
var model = [
    { text: "one", link: "#" },
    { text: "tow", link: "#" },
    {
        text: "three",
        link: "#",
        children: [
            { text: "four", link: "#" },
            { text: "five", link: "#", children: [{text:"nine", link:"#"}] },
            { text: "six", link: "#" }
        ]
    }];

$scope.model = model;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737227/using-ng-repeat-how-to-retrieve-data-from-nested-json-object?rq=1

Comment: @steady_daddy ur answer is incorrect because it support only 2 layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your html on the controller and then bind it to the view with with ng-bind-html

I would recommend a recursive approach:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yourApp')
.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
    var myModel = [
        { text: "one", link: "#" },
        { text: "tow", link: "#" }, 
        {
            text: "three",
            link: "#",
            children: [
                { text: "four", link: "#" },
                { text: "five", link: "#", children: [{ text: "nine", link: "#" }] },
                { text: "six", link: "#" }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var createHtml = function(model) {
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0 ; i < model.length ; i++) {
            var li = model[i];
            html += '<li>';
            html += li.text;
            if(li.children) {
                html += '<ul>';
                html += createHtml(li.children);
                html += '</ul>';
            };
            html += '</li>';
        }
        return html;
    }
    $scope.myHtml = '<ul>'+createHtml(myModel)+'</ul>';
});
```

and you can call it on your view with

```
<div ng-bind-html="myHtml">   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to deal with this should follow the principle of the [composite pattern](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite):

```
<composite-list items="model"> </composite-list>
```

with the composite element defined as follow:

```
 const compositeList = {
    scope: {
        items: "="
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
                <a ng-href="{{item.link}}">{{item.text}}</a>
                <composite-list ng-if="item.children.length" items="item.children"> 
                </composite-list>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
 }
```

edit: not a strict implementation, but it does his job